# Is it faster to access data from different buckets or measurements?

Tags: time-series, influxdb, influxdb-2

I have a web application that saves time series data to InfluxDB and queries it frequently. I have an entity in my business model called "Assets", and they each have different time series measurements.

Until now in my application I had about 6 or 7 "Assets" so I had separate buckets for each asset. However, a new functionality in my application will make the assets grow considerably. In a couple of weeks I will have in the order of 200, 300, maybe more in the future.

As you might expect, I want data access for the application to be as fast as possible. You should continue creating separate buckets for each "Active" or you should create a single bucket called "Active" and there separate the data by measurements and fields. What is more efficient/faster?

If there is anything else that I should consider in the decision, I would also appreciate it if you would mention it to me.